# I need help on awk

Tags: awk

AWK related help needed in one query

csv having this column

```
m1|1|0|1
m1|2|1|1
m1|3|1|1
m2|1|0|1
m2|2|0|1
m2|1|1|1
m3|1|0|1
m3|2|1|1
```

Desire Out put

```
tag|total_count|no1_repetead_in b column|no2_repeated_in b column |no3_repeated_in b column|count_of_c_column|count_of_d_column
m1|3|1|1|1|2|3
m2|3|2|1|0|1|3
m3|2|1|1|0|1|2
```

can any one help in awk

```
awk -F '|' '{c[$1]++;a[$1]+=$3;b[$1]+=$4;d[$1]+=if($2=="1")}END{for(i in a)print i"|"c[i]"|"a[i]"|"b[i]"|"d[i]|"sort"}'  /tmp/csv.txt >> desire_output.txt
```

Comment: Please share more details - what's your question about this? What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: `+=if($2=="1")` is a syntax error. Is that what you are asking about? Perhaps it'd be easier to read if you split the script up in multiple lines and indented it?

Comment: Please [edit] your Subject line to something that describes your specific problem. "I need help on awk" is not a useful Subject for anyone in future with a similar problem looking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your column names and your desired output, you can try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{c[$1]++;a[$1]+=$3;b[$1]+=$4}$2=="1"{d[$1]++}$2=="2"{e[$1]++}$2=="3"{f[$1]++}END{for(i in a)print i,c[i],d[i]+0,e[i]+0,f[i]+0,a[i]+0,b[i]+0}' csv.txt
```

Or just for better reading:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
{c[$1]++;a[$1]+=$3;b[$1]+=$4}
$2=="1"{d[$1]++}
$2=="2"{e[$1]++}
$2=="3"{f[$1]++}
END{for(i in a)
print i,c[i],d[i]+0,e[i]+0,f[i]+0,a[i]+0,b[i]+0}
' csv.txt
```

It's based on your own code, fixed the errors.

Comment: Please explain me what and how its working

Comment: if i want to take count based on two column suppose column 2 flag is 1 and column 4 is i than i want a new column appended saying a total count 1 what ever is matcing

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
             {k=$1; c[k]++; c2[k,$2]++; c3[k]+=($3==1); c4[k]+=($4==1)}
       END   {for(k in c)
                print k,c[k],c2[k,1]+0,c2[k,2]+0,c2[k,3]+0,c3[k],c4[k]}' file

m1|3|1|1|1|2|3
m2|3|2|1|0|1|3
m3|2|1|1|0|1|2
```

counts only "1"s in the 3rd and 4th columns